# Assign 1 value of a 3D array to a 1D array

Tags: c, arrays

I have a 3D array `arr1[16][8][9]` and I want to assign the contents of this array to a 1D array `arr2[36]`. So I'm trying:

```
arr2[0] = arr1[0][0][0];
arr2[1] = arr1[0][0][1];
......
arr2[8] = arr1[0][0][8];
```

I'm calling a function:

```
func_arr(int arr2[36], int arr1[16][8][9])
```

The function declaration goes like:

```
void func_arr(int arr2[36],int arr1[][8][9]);
```

But the array assignment seems to be invalid. What is a better approach to do it?

Comment: Looks ok. What´s the error? Why no loop?

Comment: Describe what you mean by "seems to be invalid".

Comment: Are you sure that's your function declaration? You might what your declaration to be something like `void func_arr(int* target, const int const* src)`.

Comment: Is `func_arr(int arr2[36], int arr1[16][8][9])` the code you're trying to use as a function call?

Comment: How have you declared `arr1`? It's not dynamically allocated, is it?

Comment: I believe the function call should be `func_arr(arr2, arr1)`.

Comment: It [works for me](http://ideone.com/88FzLT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function calling seems incorrect. Replace below line

```
func_arr(int arr2[36], int arr1[16][8][9])
```

with

```
func_arr(arr2, arr1);
```

Type of your first function argument is `int [36]` and you are passing `arr2[36]`. Assuming arr2 is `int arr2[36]`, type of `arr2[36]` is `int` and thus a type mis-match. Moreover arr2[36] is int located at address after the arr2 ends.

Comment: func_arr(arr2, arr1); may be ?

Answer (score 0):

**Why dont you use pointers for this??**

Use the function call

```
func_arr(arr2, arr1);
```

and the function definition is as

```
int func_arr(int *ptr, int (*ptr2)[16][8][9])
{
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
       for(j=0;j<3;j++)
       {
           for(k=0;k<3;k++)
           {
             *ptr = *(*((*ptr2)[i]+j)+k);
              ptr++;
           }
       }
    }

}
```

This will convert all the 3D array values to 1D array